# jQuery - shortest version for avoiding global conflicts

Tags: jquery

What happens if I do not pass the jQuery object invoking the anonymous function:

```
$(function($) {...}
```

instead of

```
$(function($) {...} (jQuery);
```

It still seems to work in all scripts so why pass it explicitly as stated everywhere on the net?

Comment: You can read more about this in the noConflict doc in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you have another library that uses $ as its main object? In that case, it is possible that the second library's object be passed to your function and your plugin break.

Imagine that you use a library of mine called foo. In that library I use `#` as my global object. To use my library, you start your code with `#` as:

```
#.getAllLinks().follow();
```

Now imagine that you use still another library which like jQuery uses `$` sign as its root object. (I think Google Analytics is such a library). In that case, the latest library to load in the browser, wins the race and takes the `$` sign under control. In this case, when you want to use `$` in your plugin, you're actually referring to a wrong library. But when explicitly passing jQuery name (jQuery's root object is both accessible using `$` sign or jQuery), then you can get sure that in the scope of your plugin, you use jQuery, not another library. :)